# How to render a Rails action without layout in html format using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How to render the *new* action without application layout and **without changing the following code structure**?

```
class FoobarController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @foobar = Foobar.new
  end

  # ...
end
```

So when someone clicks on `= link_to new_foobar_path` it should trigger an JS event that renders the action as HTML without the application layout and via Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to change the action a little bit you can achieve this by:

```
class FoobarController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @foobar = Foobar.new
    if request.xhr? # checks whether its an ajax call
      render partial: 'new'
    else
      render # thats it
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: This works, but it changes the code structure. I've solved it by overriding the `render` method in the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @Marc rails by default is full of abstractions in multiple forms. In the form of monkey patches, overrides etc. Now, you want to override the behaviour of render method such that anyone who comes after you will be baffled by the behaviour for atleast 5 mins before realizing you have overridden the behavior of default render so that an action in one controller will look good? Be my guest :)

Comment: Yes, it is an anti-pattern, I know. But it's Ruby, so what... ;)

Comment: Maybe you want to add to your answer why you do not recommend to monkey patch the render method. Otherwise I'd have to edit my question to fit your answer.